# List widgets but do not load them

Tags: listview, flutter

I have a list of stateful widgets:

```
final List<MyWidget> _list = [
  MyWidget(id: '1', title: 'One', isFav: true)),
  MyWidget(id: '2', title: 'Two', isFav: false)),
  MyWidget(id: '3', title: 'Three', isFav: false,
  MyWidget(id: '4', title: 'Four', isFav: true))
];
```

These widget are taken to create a widget selector. So all widgets should be listed within a `ListView` and if one tap onto one item, the widget is should be shown.

This is currently working.

But now I have the attribute `isFav`. So I only want to consider the widgets with `isFav == true`. Currently I am iterating through the list and filter by this attribute. Nevertheless, all elements are created and build - no matter if there are necessary or not.

Since I have many widgets that a not favorites, I want to avoid that all these widget are built if I don't interested in them to safe time and space.

Is there a way to create such a list without instandly creating all of its children? Or is it possible to keep only the class name of the widgets in a string list and create the relevant ones out of their names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you filter the List before the Build-Method the Widgets won't be created

```
    final _filteredList = _list.where((w) => w.isFav == true).toList();
```

You  might also want to use `ListView.Builder`
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView/ListView.builder.html

> This constructor is appropriate for list views with a large (or infinite) number of children because the builder is called only for those children that are actually visible.

Using the filtered List it could look something like this

```
ListView.builder(
    itemCount: _filteredList.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
      return _filteredList[index];
    })
```

Comment: Yes, I am using a ListBuilder. I didn't knew about the filtered list fact. I'll give it a try. Thank you so far